# Interactive console on deployed GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When you're testing a GAE app locally, there's an "Interactive Console" that you can use to run arbitrary code inside your application. Is there a way to do this for a deployed GAE app on [appengine.google.com](http://appengine.google.com)?

It would be useful to to be able to do datastore operations on a live application in the console.

Comment: There's nothing built-in, but http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/ has a shell program you can install (make sure you secure it in app.yaml)

Comment: Does this only work for 2.5? I tried using python 2.7 and it didn't work.

Comment: I've seen it running on a demo app somewhere, but it may have been modified to work on 2.7. I don't remember the URL, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the dev_appserver console available on production, add something like this to your app.yaml:

```
- url: /admin/.*
script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
login: admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that Appstats playground. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats